# Repeater does not appear

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

the following code should show the list of websites in a repeater but it does not (though I get no errors):
In the aspx file I have:

```
<div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Rpt1" Visible="true" runat="server"></asp:Repeater>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.GetDataItem(), "Key") %>' 
                       NavigateUrl= '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.GetDataItem(), "Value") %>'>
        </asp:Hyperlink>
    </ItemTemplate>           
</div>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) return;
    CaricaSiti();
}

protected void CaricaSiti()
{
    ListDictionary L = new ListDictionary();

    L.Add("google", @"http://google.com");
    L.Add("microsoft", @"http://microsoft.com");
    L.Add("yahoo", @"http://yahoo.com");

    Rpt1.DataSource = L;
    Rpt1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Your `<ItemTemplate>` should be *inside* your `<asp:Repeater>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repeater's [`ItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) must be *inside* of the repeater :-)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rpt1" Visible="true"  runat="server">

      <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Key") %>' 
             NavigateUrl= '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>'>

            </asp:Hyperlink>
     </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: how could i miss that? Further I found another error container.Getdataitem(), should be DataItem